# Keep business/data logic for wcf library in separate assembly?

Tags: wcf

I was thinking of have my wcf interface in its separate assembly and then the data/business logic in it's own assembly.  Is this over-architecture or is it just fine?  Does it make updating the services easier? or if their is an issue/bug, does it make fixing the bugs easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a good way to design your program.

This allows you to focus on business logic or display logic independently, which is called Separation of Concerns and is one of the most important principles in the development of quality software.

This doesn't help with "fixing" bugs so much as it helps in avoiding bugs altogether.

It also allows you to create different front-ends for the same business objects, just in case you would also like to have a scriptable Console interface or a web or Silverlight interface later on.

Comment: thanks for the answer.  Avoiding bugs would actually be better than fixing them :)